# Java in Natural Language Process: what does this following code mean? Why they are different from what we are familiar?

Tags: java, nlp

I am learning Natural Language Process using Stanford resources, the explanation on its website really confuse me, the code in the following below isn't the code that can typed in eclipse, how can I transfer these codes or is there other place to type in these codes?

There is one sentence from its webstie:
To process one file using Stanford CoreNLP, use the following sort of command line (adjust the JAR file date extensions to your downloaded release):

```
java -cp stanford-corenlp-VV.jar:stanford-corenlp-VV-models.jar:xom.jar:joda-time.jar:jollyday.jar:ejml-VV.jar -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP [ -props <YOUR CONFIGURATION FILE> ] -file <YOUR INPUT FILE>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is how you execute java code from the command line (shell, command prompt). The java code is already written and compiled in jars for this example

I guess you'd like to open the coreNLP code in Eclipse to use it directly from your java application. You can use maven to create the Eclipse project file, then in Eclipse "import - existing project".

You'll need to understand java well in order to understand and use the coreNLP code.

Answer (score 0):

All I see is setting some Jars in the classpath, then setting heap size to 2g, main class `edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP` with optional arguments and file argument whose processing you could see in the `main()` method of `class edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP`. Except the jars used what is not familiar?

Eclipse you may have to download and these jars and manually add it to projects classpath. In `Run as` option of project you can give JVM arguments which includes your heap size. It also has program arguments where you can give your program arguments like  -`file yourFile` . The syntax you see is for command line execution.